# New column is added automaticlly when filling datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I'm using linq to filling my datagrid view with this method:

```
public List<HopDongCungCap> XemHopDong()
        {
            return QL.HopDongCungCaps.ToList();
        }
```

and this is my 
[Result](http://postimg.org/image/64bdebjdp/)

My `dbo.HopDongCungCap` just has 1-4 column
but i dont know why it appears the 5th column

Note that `dbo.NhaCungCap` has a relationship with `dbo.HopDongCungCap`

Thank you for watching my question!

Comment: Without any more information it's not possible to answer that. Please read [Hot to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to project the wanted results with Linq like this:

```
var result = QL.HopDongCungCaps.Select(x => new
        {
            MaHD = x.MaHD,
            TenHD = x.TenHD,
            ThoiHan = x.ThoiHan,
            NCC = x.NCC
        }).ToList();
```

Note that I leave 'NhaCungCap' out from the result.
This will create a anonymous type.

But you can create a classobject or DTO(Dummy Transfer Object) and project the result that object. and assign that to the datagridview. (.Select(x=> new YourClassDTO...)